# PhpStorm git merge not show conflicts

Tags: git, version-control, merge, phpstorm, bitbucket

I have a project with two branches. All of them have an `X.txt` file;

I just make changes for `X.txt` in branch A, then I commit and push changes.

Then I switch to branch B, merge changes branch A.

But it just overrides the `X.txt` file. There is no conflict and no Resolve Conflict dialog shown like normal.

I just want the to resolve conflicts, not overrides my files.
How should I do?

I use BitBucket and PhpStorm for developing my project.

Comment: To occur git conflicts, most of the time you should have edited the same file from both the branches. If you haven't done so there could be no conflicts. Are you sure there should be a conflict?

Comment: @Vĩnh Nguyễn Trọng, did the answer help you solve the problem? If yes, please mark it. And it will help others who have similar question.

Comment: Thank you. My problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to merge branchA into branchB and solve the merge conflict manually, you can try these steps in phpstorm:

In branchB -> VCS -> Git -> merge changes -> select branchA for branches to merge -> select **resolve** for strategy -> merge.